# Saving files in specific folders using a for loop

Tags: python

I am trying to save various excel files that are produced in the code below to a specific folder, but keep getting "SyntaxError: invalid syntax".

```
#df = some random data
dfinvest = df[df['INVEST'] >= 0.1]
groupedinvest = dfinvest.groupby("SEDOL")
keysI = groupedinvest.groups.keys() 

save_path = "C:/Users/Documents/Python Scripts/"

for key in keysI: 
        splitdf = groupedinvest.get_group(key)  
        splitdf.to_excel(os.path.join(save_path((str(key)+ str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime(" %d-%m-%Y - Invest") )+ ".xlsx"), engine='xlsxwriter')))
```

Any help or pointing in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-5616ac4f50b7> in <module>
      1 for key in keysI: #looping through each key
      2         splitdf = groupedinvest.get_group(key) # creating a temporary dataframe with only the values of the current key.
----> 3         splitdf.to_excel(os.path.join(save_path((str(key)+ str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime(" %d-%m-%Y - Invest") )+ ".xlsx"), engine='xlsxwriter')))

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: Post the full error message. It will have a `^` pointing to where the syntax error is.

Comment: I think your parentheses in that last line are out of whack (they are all closed, but perhaps in the wrong spot). Work from the inside out.. does this make sense: `save_path((str(key)+ str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime(" %d-%m-%Y - Invest") )+ ".xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter'))` ?

Comment: `save_path` is a string, why are you trying to call it as a function?

Comment: But that should cause a different error, not a syntax error.

Comment: the `engine` argument belongs to `to_excel()` you have it nested too deeply.

Comment: It works great when I am not trying to save the data in a specific location.

Comment: Count your parentheses. You need one `)` somewhere _before_ `, engine=`, and remove one from the end of the line.  Voted to close as a typo.

Comment: Of course, that leaves the issue of trying to use `save_path(...)` as a _callable_ when it's a _string_, but that is a different problem and you will need to explain what you expect to happen when you do that

Comment: Yes, you are right. This gives me "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable". 

I am only trying to save the several excel files the loop produces somewhere else to where the code is saved.